# How to Change Binding Field Dynamically of Repeater Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, dynamic-data

I am developing a webpage having the Status of Completion.

Stage 1: DraftName
Stage 2: FinalName

I want to Bind the Repeater control depending on the Stage Completion if *Stage 1* complete then bind `<%# Eval("DraftName")%>` if *Stage 2*: then bind `<%# Eval("FinalWard")%>`.

So, how to bind conditionally the Repeater Control dynamically?

I have many databases with same condition so I don't want to hardcode after every state of completion in each Database. If both values exist still want to set any one that I need! How can I do this?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ResultsRepeater" runat="server">
     <HeaderTemplate>
     <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
              &nbsp;
          </td>
       </tr>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
           <td>
              <table width="100%">
                  <tr>
                     <td align="left" class="searchResFieldName" width="40%">
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" Visible='<%# DeletedImageVisibility(Eval("IsActive"))%>' runat="server"
                                                                ImageUrl="~/images/deleted.png" Style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; margin-left: -5px;" /><br />
       <%# Eval("UnicodeFullName")%>
   </td>
   <td width="10%">
     Constno
   </td>
   <td width="10%">
     Partno
   </td>
   <td width="10%">
     Serialno
   </td>
   </td>
   <td width="8%">
     Age
   </td>
     <td width="5%">
    Gender
     </td>
   <td width="20%">
       Cardno
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="left" class="searchResFieldName" width="35%">
        <%# Eval("EnglishFullName")%>
     </td>
     <tr>
     <td align="left">
         <%# Eval("HouseNumber")%><br />
         <%# Eval("UnicodeAddress")%>
     </td>
     <td>
       <b>
        <%# Eval("Constno")%>
       </b>
     </td>
     <td>
     <b>
          <%# Eval("FinalWard")%>
          <%# Eval("PartNumber")%>
          <%#Eval("SerialNumberFinal")%></b>
     </td>
     <td>
          <b>
            <%# Eval("SerialInPart")%>
         </b>
     </td>
           <td>
              <b>
                 <%# Eval("Age")%>
             </b>
             </td>
             <td>
              <b>
               <%# Eval("Sex")%>
              </b>
             </td>
             <td>
               <b>
                <%# Eval("CardNo")%>
               </b>
             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>
                 <%# Eval("Address")%>
             </td>
             <tr>
             <td>
             </td>
            <td class="searchResPrabhag" colspan="10" align="right">&nbsp;
           </td>
           </tr>
              </table>
                 </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                 <td>
                 <hr />
                 </td>
                 </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate>
                     <tr>
                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                     </tr>
                </table>
              </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: use `OnItemDataBound` event and `FindControl`

Comment: I got solution after 2days:  
<% if (FinalVisibility()==true)
   { %>
     <td><b><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0} -- {1}",Eval("FinalWardName"), Eval("WardSerialNumberFinal")) %>' /></b></td>
 <% } %>
 <% else
  { %>
<td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0} -- {1}",Eval("DraftWardName"), Eval("WardSerialNumberDraft")) %>' /></b> </td>
 <% } %>

Answer (score 0):

You can write an inline function that takes Container.DataItem as argument. Inside you can write your logic to return desired string...Creates less clutter in the markup